# What is the /dev/urandom equivalent on Windows JVM level

Tags: windows, java, jvm

Recently, I run into troubles because the lack of entropy and blocking rand IO caused hangs. On Linux, I can do the following:

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=/dev/urandom ./myStartScript.sh
```

What is the equivalent on Windows? We are running the app on both Linux and Windows servers, linux servers using OpenJDK JRE and Windows servers using Oracle JRE.

I found a lot of suggestions about `CryptGenRandom`, but how can I pass that to the app on the JVM level?

Comment: On Windows systems, the URLs `file:/dev/random` and `file:/dev/urandom` enables use of the [Microsoft CryptoAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_CryptoAPI) seed functionality.

Comment: @FedericoSierra I know that is the case for OpenJDK JRE on Windows, but I didn't think that's the case for Oracle JRE... Do you have a source by any chance, please?

Comment: Take a look: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunMSCAPI

Comment: @FedericoSierra I found that but there is no mention of Windows and file:/dev/urandom... I am still not completely convinced; it specifically says "On Solaris, Linux, and OS X, ..." and does not mention Windows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found documentation in jre/lib/security/java.security that confirms this.
Here is the quote

> Select the primary source of seed data for the "SHA1PRNG" and 
>   "NativePRNG" SecureRandom implementations in the "Sun" provider. 
>   (Other SecureRandom implementations might also use this property.)
>
> On Unix-like systems (for example, Solaris/Linux/MacOS), the 
>   "NativePRNG" and "SHA1PRNG" implementations obtains seed data from 
>   special device files such as file:/dev/random.
>
> On Windows systems, specifying the URLs "file:/dev/random" or 
>   "file:/dev/urandom" will enable the native Microsoft CryptoAPI seeding
>   mechanism for SHA1PRNG.
>
> By default, an attempt is made to use the entropy gathering device 
>   specified by the "securerandom.source" Security property.  If an 
>   exception occurs while accessing the specified URL:
>
> ```
>  SHA1PRNG:
>      the traditional system/thread activity algorithm will be used.
>
>  NativePRNG:
>      a default value of /dev/random will be used.  If neither
>      are available, the implementation will be disabled.
>      "file" is the only currently supported protocol type.
> ```